# Change the username ModelForm field to only accept letters and numbers?

Tags: django

I have a ModelForm that uses Django's User model. I want to change the field to only accept letters and numbers. I can change some behaviours by using this to set fields to required (see code). So could I use it to change the username field to that?

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(UserForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['first_name'].required = True
```

How could I change the username field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. You might need a [validator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/validators/) though. I haven't tried this but it might just work:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(UserForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['first_name'].required = True

    validator = RegexValidator(r'^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$',
                               'You can only enter alphanumerics')
    self.fields['username'].validators = [validator]
```

Comment: Great! I needed to change the username field, so support for international characters is no problem. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 0):

You can define a `clean_field` method for the first name field

```
def clean_first_name(self):
    name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
    if not name.isalnum():
        raise forms.ValidationError('Only alphanumeric')
    return super(UserForm, self).clean_first_name()
```